# Citrix Xenserver 5.6 vs HP BL460c G7 Networkadapter

Tags: hp, xenserver, citrix, blade-server, drivers

We have a brand new HP BL460c G7 Blade. We want to install Citrix Xenserver on it. The installer prompts for Networkdrivers since it can´t locate any supported hardware. According to HPs [QuickSpecs](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13706_div/13706_div.html) the Server uses NC553m 10Gb FlexNet adapter.
I can not find any drivers at HP´s nor Citrix´s Website.

Anyone had any luck with this (or a similar) setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NC553m is a [re-branded Emulex driver](http://www.emulex.com/products/10gbe-fcoe-cnas/hp-certified/nc553m-flexfabric-adapter/overview.html).

You can find the appropriate driver from the [Citrix website here](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX128028).

Comment: putting just a link as an answer isn't very helpful, especially if that link goes dead int he future, can you please add to your answer with a summary of the information in the link - in your own words.

Comment: Worked! Useing Citrix Xenserver 5.6 FP1 also did the trick. It has the driver included...